# Can't access an application deployed on AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

I'm trying to access a simple Asp.net core application deployed on Azure AKS but I'm doing something wrong.

This is the deployment .yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: aspnetapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: aspnet
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: aspnet
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: aspnetapp
        image: <my_image>
        resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "0.5"
              memory: 64Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

and this is the service .yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: aspnet-loadbalancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    name: aspnetapp
```

Everything seems deployed correctly

[image]

Another check I did was to enter the pod and run
`curl http://localhost:80`,
and the application is running correctly, but if I try to access the application from the browser using http://20.103.147.69 a timeout is returned.

What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you do not have an [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) deployed on your AKS as you have your application exposed directly. You will need that in order to get [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) to work.

To verify if your application is working your can use port-forward and then access http://localhost:8080 :

```
kubectl port-forward aspnetapp 8080:8080
```

But you should def. install a ingress-controller: Here is a Workflow from MS to install [ingress-nginx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli) as IC on your Cluster.

You will then only expose the ingress-controller to the internet and could also specify the loadBalancerIP statically if you created the PublicIP in advance:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: myResourceGroup # only needed if the LB is in another RG
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
spec:
  loadBalancerIP: <YOUR_STATIC_IP>
  type: LoadBalancer
```

The Ingress Controller then will route incoming traffic to your application with an Ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx # ingress-nginx specifix
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
```

PS: Never expose your application directly to the internet, always use the ingress controller

Answer (score 0):

In your Deployment, you configured your container to listen on port 8080. You need to add targetport value set to 8080 in the Service definition.

[Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service)

Comment: I  updated the service definition with `targetPort: 8080` but still not working.

Comment: The selector should be name: aspnetapp

Comment: Still timeout :(

Comment: Update your question with the changes you made to the YAML files

Comment: I updated the yml of the service